# Applying Metadata from my domain classes to my ViewModels, getting "The associated metadata type for type x contains the following unknown properties"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC 3.

I'm not sure if I am using a pattern that doesnt make sense, but it makes sense to me :-)

I have domain classes that I view as "the full deal".  Ie, they have all their possible properties defined, especially things like maximum string length, range, possibly regexps for validity checks etc.  These attributes seem to me to be domain relevant attributes.

I also have many view models that pick and choose from those domain classes what properties make sense for this particular view.  I was hoping to use MetadaType to get the annotations defined on my domain class over to my ViewModel.  This "centralizes" the relevant annotations in one place.

But, alas, it appears that using MetadataType forces me to include ALL properties defined in the referenced class (in my case the domain class) into my view model.  Not quite what I was thinking.  When I leave out properties in the view model that are present in the annotated domain class, I get the error: The associated metadata type for type 'XXX' contains the following unknown properties or fields: xxxprop. Please make sure that the names of these members match the names of the properties on the main type.

Am I just "confused" - wouldnt be the first time I assure you :-)

Is there another/better way to do what I am trying to do?

Help please?